# ContentPane NOT resizing at design time in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

i am designing a FullScreen desktop app, using Eclipse Window Builder toolkit
and, i have found this strange problem in designing
i am using GroupLayout and i have to place components on it but as you can see the difference among components that are being placed, in the image i have provided.

[image]

here is the source generated by IDE:

```
package info.visual.gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MDI {

    public JFrame frame;
    /**
     * @wbp.nonvisual location=487,159
     */
    private final JButton button = new JButton("New button");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MDI window = new MDI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MDI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));

        JButton btnButton = new JButton("button1");
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(319, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnButton)
                    .addGap(26))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(113)
                    .addComponent(btnButton)
                    .addContainerGap(125, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
        frame.setExtendedState(6);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

have a look at these lines of codes

```
/**
     * @wbp.nonvisual location=487,159
     */
    private final JButton button = new JButton("New button");
```

Thats something i am curious about, and most important this is the problem.
can anyone clarify what should i do to get the contentpane to extend to full size as frame is at design time...
thanx..

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I resolved it by resizing the frame, not the ContentPane.
Just drag and drop the right bottom of the frame (window) until you reach middle of the frame (for example), the ContentPane should now have a new size and you should see your components right.